# Выполняется блок if(){} при значении логического условия равном false!

Tags: java, if

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, как исполнение блока `if` при значении разрешающего условия равном `false`.

Есть два логических условия, и оба дают `false`, при этом они объединены оператором `&&`. Но код в блоке `if` всё равно выполняется, что не так с моей Java'ой? И как мне устранить такую "ошибку"?

Код:

```
System.out.println(objX == (int)player.myX && objY == (int)player.myY);
if(objX == (int)player.myX && objY == (int)player.myY);
{
   System.out.println(obj[i] != player);
   System.out.println("objX: " + objX + " objY: " + objY);
   System.out.println("player.myX: " + (int)player.myX + " player.myY: " + (int)player.myY);
   System.out.println(objX == (int)player.myX && objY == (int)player.myY);
   i++;
   buff[i] = player;
   System.out.println();
}
```

Вывод:

```
false  
true  
objX: 16 objY: 10  
player.myX: 1 player.myY: 1  
false
```

Comment: java сломалась :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`if(objX == (int)player.myX && objY == (int)player.myY)`**`;`**

Лишняя точка с запятой

Answer (score 7):

C Java все в порядке. У вас `;` после строки с `if` стоит. Т.е. код после `if` в любом случае выполняется.