# Почему блок if выполняется?

Tags: c#

Есть условие if:

```
if (second_digit == 9 && four_digit != 0 || second_digit == 0 && four_digit != 0)
```

и Я не могу понять почему оно выполняется!!!?

Смотря под отладчиком в Visual Studio - в момент, когда выполняется этот блок, переменные second_digit и four_digit = 0 и 1 соответственно, т.е даже первая часть условия if -

```
second_digit == 9 && four_digit != 0
```

- не должна выполнятся, т.к second_digit != 9

Подскажите пожалуйста.
P.S и нет, это не дубликат вопроса: [Выполняется блок if(){} при значении логического условия равном false!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/389652/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-if-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-false) - т.к у меня после блока if точки с запятой.

Comment: Ну так у вас во второй  части условия выполняются оба подусловия. Всё корректно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваши переменные имеют такие значения: `second_digit = 0` и `four_digit = 1`.

То есть условие `second_digit == 0` возвращает `True` и `four_digit != 0` возвращает True. Так как исходное условие выглядит следующим образом (с расставленными приоритетами):

`if ((second_digit == 9 && four_digit != 0) || (second_digit == 0 && four_digit != 0))`

Вторая группа условий возвращает `True` (так как оба условия истинны), и тогда одно из двух условий связанных логическим ИЛИ истинно, то есть и все условие истинно.

[Подробнее про логическое ИЛИ](https://www.wikiwand.com/ru/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), [подробнее про логическое И](https://www.wikiwand.com/ru/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8A%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Answer (score 1):

Ваше условие можно было бы переписать так:

```
if ((second_digit == 9 ||  second_digit == 0) && four_digit != 0)
```

(законы дистрибутивности: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Дистрибутивность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)).
Как мне кажется, так нагляднее видно, что условие выполняется при `second_digit = 0` и `four_digit = 1`.